# PdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize() throws "Object reference not set to instance of object"

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a text box annotation whose text has a specified font and size.  Code as follows:

```
void addTextBox(string inputPath,string outputPath)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));
    PdfContentByte pcb = new PdfContentByte(pdfStamper.Writer);
    BaseFont baseFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA).BaseFont;
    float fontsize = 32;
    pcb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, fontsize);
    PdfAnnotation textbox = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(pdfStamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(200, 200, 3000, 3000), "Here is a Textbox", pcb);
    pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(textbox, 1);
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

The `pcb.SetFontAndSize()` call is throwing an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

`pcb` has been instantiated by the time this error occurs, and `fontsize` has been successfully assigned its numerical value, so what's the unassigned object here?

Comment: I'm not used to seeing `new PdfContentByte(pdfStamper.Writer)`. Have you tried the standard way of creating a `PdfContentByte`? That's `pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1)`? I'm also not used to seeing `FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA).BaseFont`. Are you sure that his value isn't `null`? Why don't you use the `BaseFont.CreateFont()` method to create a `BaseFont`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, changing the `PdfContentByte` assignment to `pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1)` resolved this issue; I'll accept this answer if you post it.  The `FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA).BaseFont` value is definitely not `null`, I inspected the variable's value when the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `PdfContentByte(pdfStamper.Writer)` with `pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1)` and the problem will disappear.